# Bootstrap navbar-btn formatting on toggle mobile menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use navbar-btn in a bootstrap navbar, but make them revert to a normal link on mobile view.

I have used the visible-* classes to swap out the buttons for 'standard' nav items but I can't properly format the dropdown menu on collapse. It's the padding that I can't get to work on the two links within the visible-xs div and am assuming it's that class causing the problem.

I've tried the following (as well as many other I deleted) to format the menu but nothing has worked on all of the links:

```
.navbar-fixed-top > .navbar-collapse > .navbar-nav > li > a {padding: 10px 0;}
.navbar-collapse.collapse.in > ul > li > a {padding: 10px 0;}
```

I've also tried adding a class to the links:

```
.navbar-collapse.collapsing > ul > li > a.toggled {padding: 10px 0;}
.navbar-collapse.collapse.in > ul > li > a.toggled {padding: 10px 0;}
```

I have also tried visible-xs-inline-block and block but that made no difference either

```
    <div id="fixed-top" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">logo</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <!-- buttons visible on full-size screen only -->
            <div class="visible-lg visible-md">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                        <a class="toggled" href="#"><button type="button" class="btn navbar-btn nav-button active">login</button></a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <button type="button" class="btn navbar-btn nav-button" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">my templates <span class="caret"></span></button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu inverse-dropdown">
                            <li><a class="toggled" href="#">template 1</a></li>
                            <li><a class="toggled" href="#">template 2</a></li>
                            <li><a class="toggled" href="#">template 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <!-- non-button menu on small screen only -->
                <div class="visible-sm visible-xs">
                    <li class="active"><a class="toggled" href="login.php">login</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="toggled" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="#">my templates <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu inverse-dropdown">
                            <li><a class="toggled" href="#">template 1</a></li>
                            <li><a class="toggled" href="#">template 2</a></li>
                            <li><a class="toggled" href="#">template 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </div>
            <!-- visible on all sizes -->               
                <li><a class="toggled" href="index.php">home</a></li>
                <li><a class="toggled" href="#">link 1</a></li>
                <li><a class="toggled" href="#">link 2</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="toggled" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="#">dropdown<span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu inverse-dropdown">
                        <li><a class="toggled" href="#">link drop 1</a></li>
                        <li><a class="toggled" href="#">link drop 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I won't post the CSS here as well as but I have it all here: http://www.bootply.com/C0GXvXToTE#

Perhaps there is an easier way of achieving what I want that I'm missing. I'd prefer no javascript.

Any ideas on how I can add padding to all the links on collapse?

Comment: what do you mean by 'all the links'? I doubt that you just want to add padding (and looks like it's 'left padding' only) to the 2 links 'login' and 'my templates'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to give the elements an `id` then style them. it's more convenient than traversing through bootstrap css.

```css
#login-sm {
              padding-left: 10px;
            }
            #dropdown-sm {
              padding-left: 10px;
            }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
           <style type="text/css">
            
           </style>
           </head>
           <body>
          <div id="fixed-top" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">logo</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <!-- buttons visible on full-size screen only -->
            <div class="visible-lg visible-md">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                        <a class="toggled" href="#"><button type="button" class="btn navbar-btn nav-button active">login</button></a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li  class="dropdown">
                        <button type="button" class="btn navbar-btn nav-button" data-toggle="dropdown" role="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">my templates <span class="caret"></span></button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu inverse-dropdown">
                            <li><a class="toggled" href="#">template 1</a></li>
                            <li><a class="toggled" href="#">template 2</a></li>
                            <li><a class="toggled" href="#">template 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <!-- non-button menu on small screen only -->
                <div class="visible-sm visible-xs">
                    <li id = "login-sm" class="active"><a class="toggled" href="login.php">login</a></li>
                    <li id = "dropdown-sm" class="dropdown">
                        <a class="toggled" data-toggle="dropdown" role="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="#">my templates <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu inverse-dropdown">
                            <li><a class="toggled" href="#">template 1</a></li>
                            <li><a class="toggled" href="#">template 2</a></li>
                            <li><a class="toggled" href="#">template 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </div>
            <!-- visible on all sizes -->               
                <li><a class="toggled" href="index.php">home</a></li>
                <li><a class="toggled" href="#">link 1</a></li>
                <li><a class="toggled" href="#">link 2</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="toggled" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="#">dropdown<span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu inverse-dropdown">
                        <li><a class="toggled" href="#">link drop 1</a></li>
                        <li><a class="toggled" href="#">link drop 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Hope this helps!